# How to get the width and height of a dynamic loaded image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am displaying a few images dynamically from javascript. I need to get the image height and width. I am using "naturalWidth" and "naturalHeight" to get width and height. The first time I am loading I am getting height and width but after a few minutes, I am getting 0.

HTML:-

```
<div class="col-md-8" id="view_port_img" style="text-align: center;">
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
let img_div = 
    <img id="view_img_0" class="pointer micro_otpt view_port_img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/877/200/300" alt="user"></img>; 
    $('#view_port_img').html(img_div);
    var myImg = document.querySelector("#view_img_0");
    var imgWidth = myImg.naturalWidth;
    var imgHeight = myImg.naturalHeight;
```

In the first load, I am getting height and width but after a few mins, I am getting 0. 
Does anyone have any solution for this?

Comment: If the width and height attributes are not supplied then your option option is to open the file and determine the width and height from the file itself, which means you have to read the format according to its type, png, bmp, gif etc.  There is no magic that will do this for you and you can't do this at the client side, JavaScript on the client side cannot access the file.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you are trying to get the image size of the image which has not been loaded yet in the DOM.You have to check whether the image is loaded on DOM or not ,by either `image on load` function or `document ready`. Try this

```js
//var myImg = document.querySelector("#view_img_0");
function append_image() {

  let img_div =
    '<img id="view_img_0" class="pointer micro_otpt view_port_img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/877/200/300" alt="user">';
  $('#view_port_img').html(img_div);

}
append_image();

$(document).ready(function() {

// Your way
var myImg = document.querySelector("#view_img_0");
    var imgWidth = myImg.naturalWidth;
    var imgHeight = myImg.naturalHeight;
    console.log(imgWidth);
     console.log(imgHeight);
     
     //This also works
  console.log($('#view_img_0').width())
  console.log($('#view_img_0').height())

})

// Detect IF Image is loaded

$("#view_img_0")
    .on('load', function() { console.log("On Load",$('#view_img_0').width()); })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-8" id="view_port_img" style="text-align: center;">
</div>
```

Comment: but $(document).ready will work only on load. What about if i am loading an image on click of a button. How do I get the height and width of an image that time?

Comment: Updated My answer ,You can run `image.load()` function